# Generating Self executing JAR using Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

As per the direction in the [link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/#self-executing-jar), tried to build the JAR file for scheduling dataflow job in Airflow. Added relevant dependency in the dependency section and given main class name in the build section in the POM file. When I execute the dataflow job using below maven command then getting below error.

Could some one guide me to solve this issue.

Maven Command

```
- mvn package 
- java -jar target/sample-1.0.0.jar
```

Error Message:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/sdk/options/PipelineOptions
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions
```

My Pipeline File

```
public interface DefaultOptions extends PipelineOptions,GcpOptions,ApplicationNameOptions,DataflowPipelineDebugOptions,DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions,
BigQueryOptions,GcsOptions,StreamingOptions,CloudDebuggerOptions,DataflowProfilingOptions,PubsubOptions {
```

My Pipeline Initialization in class file

```
PipelineOptionsFactory.register(DefaultOptions.class);

DefaultOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(DefaultOptions.class);
options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
options.setProject(options.getDataFlowProjectName());
options.setTempLocation(options.getDataFlowProjectTempLocation());
options.setGcpTempLocation(options.getDataFlowProjectTempLocation());
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
```

POM File:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
     </dependency>

      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>SampleWindowJar</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cloud Dataflow dependency is not the only dependency that you'll need. You need also all the Beam SDK-related dependencies. The easiest way to obtain them is with a Maven archetype, which Beam provides:

https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/

```
mvn archetype:generate \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.beam \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=beam-sdks-java-maven-archetypes-starter \
      -DarchetypeVersion=2.11.0 \
      -DgroupId=org.yourorg \
      -DartifactId=my-beam-pipeline \
      -Dversion="0.1" \
      -Dpackage=org.yourorg.pipelines \
      -DinteractiveMode=false

cd my-beam-pipeline
```

You'll see a `pom.xml` file, and a directory with your starter pipeline that you can develop.

Once you have your archetype created, that'll include all the basic SDK dependencies, and you can add the Dataflow Runner as well:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
   <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
   <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It worked for me!. I just used this sample project as base and tried to create JAR file on top of it with the same steps which I questioned, then it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** is throwing since you didn't copy the dependencies before packaging it to jar.While running the jar jvm is trying to load class **org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions** from the dependencies. To fix that you need to add one more plugin **maven-dependency-plugin**

Sample plugin section in **pom.xml** will be like below

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/lib
                    </outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>YOUR_MAIN_CLASS_NAME_INCLUDING_PACKAGE</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

In the below link they didn't mentioned about the copying the jar. May be because of that you missed that plugin.
[Self executing JAR](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/#self-executing-jar)

After adding the correct plugins and dependencies run to build jar

```
mvn package
```

Use below command to run in dataflow

```
 java -jar target/<YOUR_PROJECT_ARTIFACT_ID>-<YOUR_PROJECT_VERSION>.jar \
   --runner=DataflowRunner \
   --project=<YOUR_GCP_PROJECT_ID> \
   --region=<GCP_REGION> \
   --tempLocation=gs://<YOUR_GCS_BUCKET>/temp/
```

To run and debug locally use DirectRunner

```
 java -jar target/<YOUR_PROJECT_ARTIFACT_ID>-<YOUR_PROJECT_VERSION>.jar \
   --runner=DirectRunner
```

Also pass your program arguments(eg: pipeline options)